# What is causing this gouging to the outer edge of my front tires?

Tags: tires

Car is a 2008 Mitsubishi Lancer FWD, I try to get it aligned every few months or so and I don't get any hard pulls in either direction if I let the steering go. Also tend to drive on fairly rough roads, think gravelly asphalt.

I noticed this sometime back and it has gotten worse over time. It's more towards the outer edges but there is a little damage to the middle as well. I plan to replace these tires very soon but I want to know if there's a specific issue or habit causing it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How old are the tires? Are you cornering hard? Brand?

Comment: Are the pressures correct? Then tends to be going into corners hard...

Comment: Tires are a little over 2 years old, sometimes but not often with the hard cornering and KUMHO. I actually just remembered that the pressure might have been dropped from 30ish to ~26 by my mechanic because it was being very sensitive to aforementioned roads and I was getting some vibrations on my dash.

Comment: Are all four tires worn the same? What sort of issues are you having that cause you to "get it aligned every few months or so"? Unless this is a race car I don't understand that need. I have seen tires worn like this before that were the result severe understeer (plowing). I would recommend following the manufacturers recommendation on tire pressure. Under inflation can cause a number of issues including loss of traction, poor steering response and overheating the tire which can lead to failure.

Comment: @iKlsR: 2 years by production date or did you buy them 2 years ago?

Comment: The gouges in the rubber do not look like any 'normal' wear that i've seen before, there's all kinds of pits and bits of rubber missing. Could it be that these tires are intended as sticky sports tires for tarmac and that the rubber compound is too soft to deal with rough gravel?

Comment: Its caused by drifitng....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIQsDBse64Q

Comment: I'm not sure production date but they were brand new when I got them. I don't have any issues really, it's just a part of my 3 - 4 month oil change, wheel balance checkup etc. It has a bit of power but I don't drive it under race conditions or speeds. I will lookup the recommended psi for these and try that.

Comment: @MadMarky Based on all the responses that is a good conclusion and I'm inclined to believe that is somewhat the case since it worsened when I moved to this place I am now where the roads are bad, I will do a bit of research.

Comment: @iKlsR you might also want to install some valve caps, especially if you drive in dusty conditions a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The model of vehicle you drive and the appearance of the tires and wheels would lead one to believe that these are performance tires, rather than mundane rubber donuts for an automobile.

If you check the specific model of tire that you are using, you can determine what level of performance standards would be applied to the rubber.

"Sticky" tires will give great performance in acceleration and cornering and will also have very low wear durability. The damage to the tread is consistent with your description of rough roads especially if that is combined with softer rubber compounds.

From the [Tire Rack web site](https://tires.tirerack.com/tires/Hardness):

> UTQG numbers are assigned to indicate a tires overall level of
>   performance and tread hardness. These numbers beginning at 0 for race
>   products and traveling north of 800 for some of the longest lasting
>   all-season tires, are nothing more than a general guideline to assist
>   customers in making their correct tire purchase.

A more comprehensive discussion can be found within the above linked location or directly at [this link](https://blog.tirerack.com/blog/motorsport-messages-from-marshall/utqg-treadwear-numbers-what-do-they-mean).

Comment: Exactly what i was thinking about, but then in a better prepared answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, never thought of this really. I will poke around and report back!